# User inactive for 15min

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, angular5, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to implement user idle activity in my project.

If the user is idle for suppose 15 min, He should auto logout.

Any suggestions?

Project standard: asp.net core, Angular 5, Azure b2c.

Comment: I found solution with ngx-inactivity handling at angular view side. But I couldn’t handle 15 min and further 15 min functionality. Handling at view may not be a good practice. Any help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Owin implementation will be good to handle all the stuff.

Comment: I tried possible ways with me. But failed other than commented approach. So looking for suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by "Adler"? Do you mean "idle"?

Comment: Yup sorry. Updated!

Answer (score 2):

Try following in the startup

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
});
```

Comment: So it is telling me that UseCookieAuthentication is obsolete. I changed it to UseAuthentication but it will not take a new CookieAuthenticationOptions as an argument. So, how do I use the object I created  from cookie options to achieve the same thing in .net Core 2.1? Also, would this just logout after 15 minutes or does it actually check for idle? And if so how does it check for idle time?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with Angular. Added few commands for mouse movement and keyboard key press. Then firing an event when there is movement and hence clearing time interval. If time idle met 15 min , calling a method.
Thanks All for Support.

Answer (score -1):

use this in web config under configuration

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="15" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Not applicable to core.